# When resizing an image with PHP, the page goes blank

Tags: php, image, resize

I'm fairly new to PHP. I have a function written to scale an image and save a thumbnail. The function is working (thumbnails being created) but any time it runs the the page loads a blank page with only an empty image tag - I can't view the source of the page (because there isn't one?).

If the function doesn't run the page loads fine.

```
function scaleImage($id)
{
    header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
    $si = imagecreatefromjpeg("img/dribbble/standard_resolution/{$id}.jpg");
    $si_x = imagesx($si);
    $si_y = imagesy($si);

    $di_x = 210;
    $di_y = 158;
    $di = imagecreatetruecolor($di_x, $di_y);

    imagecopyresampled($di, $si, 0, 0, 0, 0, $di_x, 
                $di_y, $si_x, $si_y);

    imagejpeg($di,"img/dribbble/low_resolution/{$id}.jpg",90);
};
```

Why is the page blank when the function runs and how can I fix this?

Comment: Turn on error reporting

Comment: Error reporting is on but i see no errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try outputting image without `$filename` argument: `imagejpeg($di, null, 90);`

Comment: Produces same results - Plus i want to save the file, so dont i need the a path/filename?

Comment: @Scotosaurus `imagejpeg($di, null, 90);` outputs correctly (tested), just call again with filename: `imagejpeg($di,"img/dribbble/low_resolution/{$id}.jpg",90);`